# I tried to download a image file using power shell and i got the following error

Tags: powershell, download

```
PS C:\> $p = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

PSC:\>$p.DownloadFile("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ec/Soccer_ball.svg","C:Users\Tamil\Downloads\Soccer_ball.svg.jpg")
```

> ```
>  Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An
> exception occurred during a WebClient request."
>
> At line:1 char:1
> + $p.DownloadFile("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ec/Socce
> ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
> ```

[image]

Comment: The local path is not valid. `C:Users\Tamil\Downloads\Soccer_ball.svg.jpg"`, you're missing a backslash after `C:`.

Answer (score 0):

As Ash already mentioned in comment that local path is not valid and you need to provide the same extension as the image to download. So that you can download the image properly and able to view it.

I was able to download the image using:

```
$p.DownloadFile("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ec/Soccer_ball.svg","C:\test.svg")
```